# Lua Api unit test

Tags: unit-testing, lua

Is there are any existing unit tests for lua Api? I've been searching for like an hour and all I found is this link -  http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lua/lua5.1-tests.tar.gz
does somebody know some tests except this?

Answer (score 2):

> Unit testing is about testing your code during development, not in production. Typically you start by preparing the testing environment, writing some code that calls production code and check expected results with actual results.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/UnitTesting

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

See [lua-TestMore](http://fperrad.github.com/lua-TestMore/).

Answer (score -2):

No, those are the only ones that exist.